# How to edit an existing Nested style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I applied a Nested style in paragraph style. But then I want to change the nested style and couldn't find how to edit or delete this nested style.

Anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: Does click/right-click not work?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a nested style from the Paragraph Style Options dialog, you're actually creating a character style.

To edit that style, choose Window->Styles->Character Style this window will popup and the nested style you've created will be listed there.

[image]

You can then edit it by double clicking it or right clicking and choosing Edit "Char..."